# how to resolve System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sybdrvado20.dll': for sybase

Tags: vb.net, sybase

I used the sybdrvado20.dll for my windows service development with vb.net for sybase db connectvity.When i prepared the setup and run on windows server then below sybase error getting.

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sybdrvado20.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: If the error message is telling you that the DLL can't be found then the DLL is not there on that machine.  The obvious solution is to make sure that it is.  How you do that is not a VB.NET question.

Comment: That DLL in turn needs a bunch of [*other* DLLs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20066.0215/html/adonet2155/adonet215515.htm).  Forgetting to deploy them produces this error.  Fwiw, the list is not complete, it also needs the VS2005 C++ redist to be installed.  Using the Sybase installer would certainly be the best approach.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i can also read the error but DLL is already there in that machine,this windows service developed in vb.net then how come qns not related to vb.net

Comment: @Hans Passant  using sybase installer means , sybase client full installation .is it?

Comment: *"DLL is already there in that machine"*. I guess I missed where you specified that in the question. If a library is part of a package and it depends on other libraries in that package then you need to install the package.

Comment: *"how come qns not related to vb.net"*. If you VB.NET code works on your machine then the VB.NET part is done. How to deploy dependencies is not anything specifically to do with VB.NET.